# Web Setup Project - Repair to overwrite files

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer, repair, web-setup-project

I have a web setup project that creates an MSI.  After first installation, my web site has some config files that can be modify manually.

When triggering that MSI again, I am offered to repair the installation, when I select to do so, the installation runs, but the config files that were modified previously are no replaced with default config files contained in the MSI.

I am looking for a way to overwrite those files when a repair is done.

EDIT: The setup project is built using a Visual Studio Web Setup project.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you building your MSI?  Is it a Setup project, WiX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to use a batch file to call my MSI. It is not great since we end up with two files for the installation. I could not find another way.  I am still open to suggestion.  Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off
msiexec /x "%1" /quiet >out.txt
if errorlevel 1 goto installNew

:installNew
msiexec /i "%1" >>out.txt

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default config files each as the Key file in their own component.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, we can only have one Key file per project and I therefore see two problems with this solution: 
- we already have a Key file for each of our projects
- we have more than one config file per component